# R: Why is this outer-call so slow? How can I speed it up?

Tags: r

Let `a, b` be two vectors of different length. I need to set up a matrix with elements `exp(-1i*a*b)`, meaning for every pair of elements in `a, b`, I want to multiply by the imaginary unit, and then take exponentials.

Okay, so I pull out the outer function and write

`outer(a, b, FUN = function(x,y) exp(-1i*x*y))`

but for large vectors `a, b`, this is painfully slow. I'm actually surprised at how slow it is. All I'm doing is setting up the matrix - I haven't even used it in any calculations, and yet this is super slow.

Is there any alternative to speed this up?

Comment: What is large in your context? If you need to do this regularly you might have a look at the Rcpp library and rewriting that in c++.

Comment: `exp(-1i*tcrossprod(a, b))` is a little bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

What BLAS are you using? The default one is quite slow.

You can install [OpenBLAS](https://www.openblas.net/) which is significantely faster.

On my system running

```
a <- runif(1e5, -2, 2) 
b <- runif(2e3, -4,3)
t <- exp(-1i*tcrossprod(a, b))
```

takes 10 seconds and produce a 3Gb matrix.

- Manjaro linux
- R-3.6.2
- OpenBLAS
- i7 1065 16Gb RAM